# Conditional Formatting if Cell <> Cell Above

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'd like to apply a Fill colour to a cell, if it has a different value to the cell above it (same column).

I could do that for one cell, by using Conditional Format Rules

- Apply to range = target cell
- Format rules = If not equal to
- Value or formula = previous cell

However, the formatting failed when I dragged the cell down through the column (the range) so they would all get the same formatting - it **always** referenced the original Value, instead of using the "cell above this one".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In conditional formatting you do not have to drag down a cell.
Instead you need to apply it in a range.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help . For some reason, it's highlighting the cell BEFORE the one that changed!  Followed your example exactly, Range:  E6:E29;  Custom formula is:  =E7<>E6.

Comment: Ha, found my problem, I didn't "exactly" follow your example... my range should have been E7:E29,  not E6:E29!  Works perfectly now, thank you for your time!  Cheers, Max